# Wording a sentence for "A, B, C, D, or E" with inclusive and exclusive "or"

Tags: expressions, phrasing, disjunction

In my papers, I often need to formulate disjunctions textually (for example, when providing conditions for the fulfillment of a statement).

Let's see two examples:

1. > When you eat (a) apple, (b) pear, (c) orange, (d) banana, or (e) pinapple,
   > you provide important vitamins for your body.

   (inclusive disjunction)
2. > I don't know whether Joe has (a) one, (b) two, (c) three, (d) four, or (e) five children.

   (exclusive disjunction)

Of course, the meaning of *or* is clear in these sentences, but one could give examples, where it is not evident whether inclusive or exclusive *or* is used.

Is there any way to emphasize the real meaning of *or* in (1) and (2)?

I usually fix in my papers that *A, B, C, ..., or Z* always indicates an inclusive disjunction, but what can I do when *A, B, C, ..., or Z* should mean an exclusive disjunction? How should I express such an exclusive choice?

Comment: Different sentences may need different specifying strategies, but an obvious one for (2) which includes numbers is 'I don't know whether Joe has exactly (a) one (b) two (c) three (d) four or (e) five children.' (I'd omit commas as unnecessary clutter here, as the bracketed formatting letters offset quite adequately, but check with your in-house style guide.) (For (1), 'all or any of' is cumbersome but works. Slash for 'and/or' is itself ambiguous.) The inclusive/exclusive _or_ ambiguity is well known.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for this important ingredient to my question. The problem with (1) is not only "all or any of them", but "all, any of them, any two of them, any three of them, or any four of them" (shortly, at least any of them?). This makes multiple (triple, quadruple, etc.) disjunctions even more difficultly explicable.

Comment: Yes, even 'all or any of ...' is '*inherently*' ambiguous but has a default interpretation of 'any subset of' rather than 'the whole set or any single member of' in standard usage. Of course, 'any subset of' is the unarguable way to stipulate inclusive disjunction (subsets, unlike proper subsets, including the original set) but is mathematical jargon. 'Any one of' usually works for exclusive disjunction, and 'any one taken singly' underlines. [What does a or b ... mean](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508902/what-does-a-or-b-does-not-mean/508912#508912)(not a dupe) is worth a look

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a contraction for non-exclusive or?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/491039/is-there-a-contraction-for-non-exclusive-or) (@Jason Bassford's doubtless unwelcome answer ... and he only gets as far as a two-element set).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that your comments are more useful than the answer to the question you linked, because that answer is restricted only to binary formulas.

Comment: Just precede your list by ***any one of...*** or ***any combination of...***, according to the required sense.

Comment: Please show us an example of an unclear *or* that you are worried about. Also, are you actually writing "(a) one, (b) two, (c) three, (d) four, or (e) five" instead of *one, two, etc*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin My instances where `or` is ambiguous are mainly of mathematical origin. I have recently had a mild dispute with my group leader over the following sentence: `A spectroscopic database contains measured or computed transitions`. He noticed that it can actually contain both, while I insisted on that this is included in the sentence (since `or` is inclusive here). The inclusivity of `or` was confimed by a follow-up sentence which stated that measured and computed transitions are usually mixed, therefore we cannot make a distinction between measured and computed databases.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I generally use (a), (b), (c), ..., or (z) if the predicates following these symbols are long.

Comment: *A spectroscopic database can contain both measured and computed transitions.*

Comment: Is this simply a variation of the familiar problem of how to disambiguate *or* in everyday English? The question does not make it clear how there being five disjuncts in each of the examples (rather than just two) is supposed to affect the problem.

Comment: @TinfoilHat has it correct. In this case you would not worry about *or*, but rather just say it a different way.

Answer (score -2):

Your question looks like how you can make "or" explicit between inclusive or exclusive.

1. The context could provide information to distinguish them.
2. You can add inclusive or exclusive, using parentheses like 'or(inclusive)', 'or(exclusive)'

ex) the probability of head or tail of one coin(one flip):

head or tail(inclusive (or)) = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1

head or tail(exclusive (or)) = 1-1/2 = 1/2